# How to remove a control in python - mechanize?

Tags: python, controls, mechanize

Knowing the API to add a new Control is

```
 br.form.new_control('text','ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fooBar',{'value':''})
 br.form.fixup()
```

How could I remove a Control in python mechanize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ctrl = br.form.find_control('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fooBar')
ctrl.disabled = True
```